# Save result of easyocr in veriable and print it with all data at same line

Tags: python, python-3.x, ocr

I am using easyocr to detect mrz of passport:

.py code:

```
import easyocr
import cv2
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'], gpu=False)
result = reader.readtext(gray)
for detection in result:
    text = detection[1]

    print(text.upper(), end="")
    # PCSDNKHADIGA<ABAKAR<BABIKER<MUS****<<<<<<<<<***************************<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<*
```

I want to save result in variable, problem is when i use 's = (text.replace('\n', ''))' and print 's' the result not all is the same line Like:

```
PCSDNKHADIGA<ABAKAR<BABIKER
<MUS***<<<<<<<<<
*****************<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<*
```

How to save all result to variable and then print it at same line?

Any kind of help please?

Comment: How are you running your code? Does `text` contain `'\r'` characters? I suggest using a debugger to view the actual contents of `s` to check if it is what you want. The output might be displayed as multiple lines due to soft wrapping that just affects the display and is not related to the actual data.

Comment: to save your results in variable try using dictionary data type. to print all the result in same line use string concatination .. take each result as string strip the newline charecter and and add with next result

Comment: @Bikiran Das Can you help me how to do that?

Comment: @Samer Adnan have answered your request

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes, the code save result at 3 sperate lines, I just want to save all result at same line like in 'print(text.upper(), end="")' but i cant use 'end=' at saving result to variable, can you help me to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to achive the result in single line

```
temp = ''
for detection in result:
    text = detection[1]
    temp = temp + text.strip()  # this will strip spaces at the end .. use it for  
    # other special characters according to your text.

print(temp.upper(), end="")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for reply

Comment: @SamerAdnan welcome